# Create a report with 3 or more levels with c#

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

```cs
public class ClassA{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    List<ClassB> ListClassB { get; set; }
    List<ClassC> ListClassC { get; set; }
}
public class ClassB{
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
    public string Property4 { get; set; }
    List<ClassD> ListClassD { get; set; }
}
public class ClassC{
    public string Property5 { get; set; }
    public string Property6 { get; set; }
    public string Property7 { get; set; }
}
public class ClassD{
    public string Property8 { get; set; }
    public string Property9 { get; set; }
    public string Property10 { get; set; }
}
```

Hello everyone,

The issue here is that I need to create the report using `.rdlc` reports from an object that has a structure similar to `ClassA`. Currently, I've only been able to create a 'master-detail' report only considering the properties from `ClassA` and `ClassB`
This was achieved from next sources:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/rdlc-subreport-using-c-sharp-and-wpf/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-YkNo1Os3Y

But now, I haven't been able of including the data from `ClassC` using the same approach, since there is no way for setting the datasources for the 3rd level.

Any guidance, or source for solving this issue is always welcomed.

Jsimon

**Update**

I made a quick and small prototype which implements a report with two levels. For the 2nd level, the only thing we need to do is to implement the `SubreportProcessing` event. Here is the code.

```cs
        private void LoadApplicationsCatalog()
        {
            using (IdentityDataContext context = new IdentityDataContext())
            {
                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                var applicationsCatalog = context.spGetApplicationsCatalog().Select(a => new { a.IdentityApplicationCatalogId, a.Name, a.IdentityApplicationId }).ToList();
                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("ApplicationCatalog", applicationsCatalog));

                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += LocalReport_SubreportProcessing;

                this.reportViewer1.Refresh();
                this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }
        }

        private void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
        {
            int identityApplicationId = Convert.ToInt32(e.Parameters[0].Values[0]);
            using (IdentityDataContext context = new IdentityDataContext())
            {
                var applications = context.IdentityApplications.Where(a => a.IdentityApplicationId == identityApplicationId).ToList();

                ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("Application",applications);
                e.DataSources.Add(datasource);
            }

            var applicationCatalogReport = (LocalReport)sender;

        }
```

Unfortunatly, I haven't found a way for filling up the datasources for a third level.

Comment: On your link look at step 14.  If you add another class than you need to add columns next to Employees or in the Employee column have two tables one for class C and another for class D,

Comment: According to what you say, that only would get me a 2-level report. Following the example from the employees, what I need is a way to add a 3rd table inside each Employee row.

Comment: Class B and Class C are exclusive. None of the properties are the same. You have two tables where class A contains the two tables.  One table having Class B and the other table having Class C.  So class B is the Employee Column and Class D is the Departments.  Class C is just one table with three columns 5,6,7

Comment: Not sure if I get it right. 
ClassA -> Departments 
ClassB -> Employees
ClassC -> Not mapped in the example, but lets say it is Supervisors
ClassD -> Not mapped in the example, but lets say it is Addresses

In the example it has only a report considering Departments (ClassA) and Employees (ClassB). It is true, that if I add a new column next to Employee, I would be able to add Supervisors (ClassC), as you pointed out, Supervisors(ClassC) and Employees (ClassC) are exclusive. 

The issue here is that I need to display the list of addresses(ClassD) for each employee.

Comment: Then class D becomes the rows of the table in the cells with columns being properties 8, 9, & 10.  Class B are the rows of The Employee Column with the names of rows being property 3 & 4

Comment: You're right. Somehow I haven't been able to add the rows of class D, and that's what I am struggling with.

Comment: It looks like step 11 in first link is adding male/female and it is using subreport.

Comment: @djweng thank you for your help. I was able to solve it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days, I found this [How to process subreport of a subreport in rdlc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715245/how-to-process-subreport-of-a-subreport-in-rdlc) which helped me to solve the creation of reports with 3 or more levels.